# columns matching based on third column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like:

```
    Name  id  precision
0  John   1          1
1  John   1          2
2  John   2          3
3  Marc   1          3
4   Tom   2          1
```

here the code to generate it:

```
pd.DataFrame([{'Name': 'John', 'id': 1, 'precision': 1}, 
{'Name': 'John', 'id': 1, 'precision': 2}, 
{'Name': 'John','id': 2, 'precision': 3}, 
{'Name': 'Marc', 'id': 1, 'precision': 3}, 
{'Name': 'Tom', 'id': 2, 'precision': 1}])
```

I have different algos that find the correspondence btw Name and id. Each algo has its own precision reported in the corresponding column (the smaller the better). Eventually I would like to get the best matching if any.

The desired result is:

```
    Name  id  precision
0  John   1          1
4   Tom   2          1
```

John should match with 1 because it is the only one matching with a precision of 1 (Marc has a precision of 3).

Tom should match with 2 because it is the only one matching with a precision of 1.

I am trying with:

```
df['min'] = df.groupby('Name').precision.transform(min)
```

To find the minimum, but I am having troubles in extracting then the desired result.

Comment: And `Marc` is removed? Can you explain why?

Comment: because once found the correspondence btw Name and id is unique. In this case John get the id 1 because he has a better precision (of 1). Marc does not get the id 1 because the algo found that this matching is possible with a worst precision (of 3)

Comment: basically for one Name I have 1 id only and for 1 id I can have 1 Name only

Comment: Why not select all the precision that is equal to 1 using boolean indexing like `df[df['precision'].eq(1)]`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to group on the 'id' column instead of name.

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id')['precision'].idxmin()]
```

Output:

```
   Name  id  precision
0  John   1          1
4   Tom   2          1
```

Comment: nice `idxmin` :-)

Answer (score 1):

No need `groupby`

```
df.sort_values(['id','precision']).drop_duplicates(['id'],keep='first')
Out[813]: 
   Name  id  precision
0  John   1          1
4   Tom   2          1
```